# Plotting a pie chartof value_counts() using plotly express

Tags: python, plotly

How does one plot a `pie` for value_counts() using **plotly express** for the following series:

```py
import pandas as pd
import string, random
s = pd.Series(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase) for _ in range(100))
```

I can see that it can be done through go using:

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go
go.Figure(data=[go.Pie(labels=s.value_counts().index, values=s.value_counts().values)])
```

Answer (score 3):

There are four display types, label, text, value and percentage, which can be combined. [Reference page](https://plotly.com/python/reference/pie/)

```
import plotly.express as px

fig = px.pie(s, values=s.value_counts().values, names=s.value_counts().index)
fig.update_traces(hoverinfo='label+percent', textinfo='value')
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: this doesn't seem to be different from what I have given in second part of my query. I am interested in finding an equivalent in **plotly express**.

Comment: The code has been updated with poorly expressed. The technique is the same.